# Game Room Population Tracker (C#)

Tags: c#

I am  the creator of a bot for Astroflux (online game) that goes by the name of ChatDaemon. In order to develop more advanced functionality, I need the program (C#, coded in Windows Visual Studio 2017) to keep track of which users are in which game room, so that a specific room can be closed or notified of an event. Essentially, I need to have a list of rooms, which each room containing a list of the players in that room.

Hard Upper Limits:

- 150 players max
- 40 rooms max
- 20 players per room max

I had tried looking around here for the solution to my problem, but it seemed that all previous questions were for problems too different from mine to be useful. It's entirely possible that I don't know quite how to word my question to find what I'm looking for though, so if this is a duplicate please point me in the right direction.

The code I have tried using (with epic failure :D) is this:

```
Dictionary<List<string>, List<string>> WhoIsWhere = 
  new Dictionary<List<string>, List<string>>();
```

The dictionary seems to work, but I have no idea how to use it as i need to.

Simple example of what i need:
We have 3 rooms and 5 people distributed between them.

```
1:a,b,c

2:d

3:e
```

a moves to an empty system and creates room 4, and e moves to room 2, closing room 3. We now have:

```
1:b,c

2:d,e

4:a
```

In short, I need to be able to move a player from room 1 into another room, create new rooms in my list of lists, and delete them when everyone leaves a specific one. I have no idea how to do this. Would anyone be able to offer some advice? I'll try to keep an eye on this thread to answer any questions you might have.

Note:
Don't worry about how the program is notified when someone moves, I have that taken care of. It scans for movement every 10 seconds.

Suggestion:
Would it be possible to have something that would work like the following?

```
WhoIsWhere.Add("room1");
WhoIsWhere[room1].Add("newPlayer");
WhoIsWhere[room2].Remove("oldPlayer");
WhoIsWhere[room3].Clear();
WhoIsWhere.Remove("room4");
foreach (string userId in WhoIsWhere[room3])
{
    //send a message
}
```

Comment: `Dictionary<List<string>, List<string>> WhoIsWhere` looks very strange - what is the `List` key supposed to represent? Also it will make using such a key rather awkward (compared to e.g.: a simple `string` as key)

Comment: `Dictionary<List<string>, List<string>>` even if this would compile, I think you want to use `Dictionary<string>, string>`, as the dictionary is already a collection

Comment: oh, i see your point. It should be Dictionary<string, List<string>> instead of two lists. I must have thoughts that since i wanted a list of lists, it should be two lists in the dictionary. Whoopsie ._.

Comment: Would it be ok to make an actual `Room` class, that has an id/name and a list of the players that are inside?

Comment: That would work, as long as i can manipulate and access the values like i specified above. I started coding about 8-9 months ago, and the only code I know is what i needed to build what i have so far. I didn't know what casting was until last week.

Answer (score 0):

I would create some simple classes/interfaces for this problem.
You got 2 different entities in this situation.

The first one is a player. A simple interface would be sth. like:

```
public interface IPlayer{

    string Name { get; set; }

    ... other information about the player you need in you application...
}
```

And the other one is the room that should containing an expandable list of players.

```
public interface IRoom{

    string Name { get; set; }

    IList<IPlayer> Players { get; set; }

    // You can add players to the list with .Add(item) but maybe you want to validate the action or sth. like that.
    void AddPlayer(IPlayer player);
}
```

So now you can just create classes which are implementing the interfaces and you maintain a list of rooms somwhere in you application that contains the information you need.

Comment: Are interfaces really necessary here? The way I understand the question OP only has one type of room and player, so just creating classes straight up should be fine

Comment: @UnholySheep Of course he could also create just classes but I thought that the game could contain different kind of rooms or player and creating the interfaces is not that much work.

Comment: ^^ What holy says plus: The Player list really should not be public. The interface should not define *how* an implementor keeps the players.

Answer (score 0):

`Dictionary<GameRoom,List<PlayerModel>>` would be better in your case.`GameRoom` is a class where contains a room properties such as, room id,name,title.The same goes on `PlayerModel` for players.You can achieve the same thing without usage of `Dictionary`.For example,`GameRoom` may contain active players list.
I would suggest you to use player array in a GameRoom class.You can use observable pattern to keep track of active players,where it may notify you that - who actively stays in the room,who is left.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is basically have a lookup on a one-to-many relation.
( One Room contains 1+ Players, One Player can only be in one Room )

Let me suggest just another approach:

A List of KeyValuePairs<sup>1</sup>, *that allows for duplicate Keys to exist*. That way you can have a data structure like this:

```
Room# Player
1     Bob
1     Cindy
2     LadysMan123
3     Shooter92
3     SuupaHaxxor
```

That way you can use LinQ to get you for example:

- All user in room x
- Room ID of user A

And: If the last user in a room leaves it, it will automatically disappear.

I would then go on and encapsulate that datastructure in a class, so you can provide convenient access. (I.e. methods like `IEnumerable<Player> GetPlayersInRoom( int roomId )` )

---

<sup>1</sup> Doesn't necessarily need to be literally `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.

Comment: what else could it be though besides a list of keyvaluepairs? perhaps I'm naive.

Comment: @modtrafastroflux Well, instead of `KeyValuePair` you could use `string[]` or a custom class with two string properties or a `Tuple<string,string>` ...